# Is there a category whose objects are elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and morphisms are vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory

Consider a category whose objects are elements of the set $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Consider two points $A=(0, 0)$ and $B=(1, 1)$. 
Define $Hom(A, B)$ to be the set with just one element, the vector $\vec{AB}$.
Composition of morphisms would be just addition of vectors and identity would just be the zero vector.

This seems like it is a proper category. Is there name for such a construction in the literature?

Comment: Do you mean that $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$ would be the single element $(b_1-a_1, b_2-a_2)$ if $A=(a_1,a_2)$ and $B=(b_1,b_2)$?  Just trying to understand your morphisms.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: Can you elaborate - isn't vector addition associative?

Comment: I guess it's fine.  I was worried about the tails not lining up the right way, but I think I was wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It kind of feels like this construction will work with any group, not necessarily a vector space. If I take a group $G$, the category that I'll end up with will be a *groupoid*, where $\operatorname{Hom}(g,h) = \{g^{-1}h\}$. Every morphism is invertible, justifying me calling the category a groupoid.

I'm not very familiar with category theory, but this seems somewhat like it should be called the [discrete groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+category) associated to a group $G$: every morphism is invertible and morphisms are uniquely determined by their endpoints.

ETA – @CliveNewstead points out that this is actually a *co*discrete groupoid.

Comment: I like this way of thinking about it.  Seems clearer that composition will work out correctly.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is actually a [*codiscrete* groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codiscrete+groupoid), not a *discrete* groupoid. In a discrete groupoid, the only morphisms are identities, meaning that there is no morphism between distinct objects. In a codiscrete groupoid, there is a unique morphism between any two objects.

Comment: Thank you! That jives much better with what I thought a discrete category ought to mean.

Comment: This is sometimes called an action groupoid.

Comment: Codiscrete groupoid sounds exactly like the thing I described, thanks!